# Vaadin: How do I align all my components to the left in formLayout?

Tags: vaadin

Vaadin: How do I align all my components to the left in formLayout instead of being spaced out evenly?

Comment: Please add the code, you are currently using. And also consider adding an Image for what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you align it with CSS.